# Filter view with multiple displays

Tags: views

Using Drupal 7. I have a view with several page displays, 2 of them being /review and /mentions. I have some exposed filters on these pages visible on a side block of the page.

When clicking the apply button to filter the content, I get redirected to /review?filter=....
whether I am on the /review page or /mentions page.

How can I make the filter work so that
- when filtering the /review page, I land on /review?filter=...
- when filtering the /mentions page, I land on /mentions?filter=...

Thanks for your help,
Jerome

Comment: Your question not understandable - explain it clearly

Comment: More specifically, the action of the filter form is 'review' on both pages. It should be 'review' on the /review page and 'mentions' on the /mentions page.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong.

I assumed that the exposed filter block for the view was the same for all displays of that view, When it actually creates 1 block per display.

I disabled the block "Exposed form: filter_view-page" for the /mention path and added the another block "Exposed form: filter_view-page_2" for it.

Works fine now.